# Why is the variable arity record component not inferred with custom constructor?

Tags: java, arity, java-record, java-16

Trying out some code with `record` and record components. I was making use of the variable rarity components and was struck with a compile-time error over a custom constructor.

```
public record Break<R extends Record>(R record, String... notifications) {

    public Break(R record, String... notifications) {
        System.out.println("record: " + record + " and notifications: " + Arrays.toString(notifications));
        this.record = record;
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

    // compile error: non canonical record constructor must delegate to another costructor
    public Break(R record) { 
        System.out.println("record: " + record);
        this.record = record;
    }

    public Break() {
        this(null); // this works 
        // actually intelliJ suggests it uses the constructor that is not compiling
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Break<>(new Break<>());
    }
}
```

What I am curious to understand is, how is the similar constructor inferred when invoked via another custom constructor without any components provided for initialization.

Comment: My understanding is that non-canonical constructors are NOT required to delegate only to the canonical constructor. Java can still resolve the chain and detect cycles. So assuming your `Break(R record)` delegated to the canonical constructor, calling `Break()` would still successfully end up initializing all components.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with variable arity.  All record constructor chains must "bottom out" in the canonical constructor (which may be specified using the compact form), variable arity or not.  This manifests as a requirement that each non-canonical constructor must delegate to another constructor; eventually this means chains bottom out in at the canonical.

You can fix your bad constructor with:

```
public Break(R record) {
    this(record);
}
```

But, you don't even need to declare this constructor all, since the canonical constructor can handle calls of the form `new Break(r)` already.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I could have private constructors that bypass the canonical constructor. Reasons include not making a defensive copy of an array if I know the passed array will not be modified in the future. Maybe by explicitly calling `super()` to show that this is not an accident? Current workaround uses ThreadLocals to set a flag - but it's usually not worth that effort.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I think you will find that such games mostly just move the problem around.  Do your accessors do defensive copies?  Do you update `Object::equals` to reflect this? Note that there is a refined contract in `Record::equals` which is likely undermined by tricks like this.

Comment: I always ask myself: What if `java.lang.String` would have been a record? Makes sense from a few POVs. What I try to avoid is copying the array twice, so I want to implement an constructor like [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L3670). Looking at the evolution of String, it becomes clear that there also needs to be a story on how to convert a record into a regular class. Problem there is the reflective support - `Class.getRecordComponents` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: On a higher level, the role of the canonical constructor is to check and enforce invariants like "list is sorted", "no subsequent modifications are made to a mutable type"... There are often operations that do not change those invariants - adding a fixed value to all members doesn't change the order. Not letting the temporary array escape doesn't change the immutability requirement. Sometimes checking the invariants can be expensive. And there should be a way to say "I know what I am doing, no need to check again".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Maybe the way to do that is to write a class?  Remember, records are not a syntactic feature (though their syntax is nice), they are a semantic feature -- nominal tuples. Everything (almost) that records can do, classes can do (except implement `java.lang.Record`.)

Comment: Consider a normalized vector: `record NormVector3D(double x, double y, double z) {...}`. This is a tuple, but with the invariant `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1`. Swapping two coordinates don't change that invariant, but the canonical constructor has to enforce that invariant again. Yes, it can be implemented as a class, but a vector is still a nominal tuple. My argument is: There are (maybe rare) cases, where the restriction to that the canonical constructor has to be called is counter-productive.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I agree that the current definition may exclude some (agreed: rare) cases that would still semantically be candidates. And in an even rarer set of cases, the performance difference might actually matter (but I suspect this is much much rare.)   But that alone is still not enough to conclude we've picked the wrong set of rules; picking the rules involves balancing a lot of different considerations, and this is only one of them.  Design involves tradeoffs; here, we're excluding some possible good cases in order to exclude more bad cases. Ask me in 5 years whether we got it right...